# Powershell - Find dublicate values in custom object arraylist

Tags: powershell

I've got an Arraylist with custom objects and want to find all objects where "Jobname" is identical. Group-Object does not work the way I wanted it because it just counts all properties (10). I'm even starting to think that I'm using the Arraylist wrong. The creation of the objects in the code is just for testing, in reality I'm using a loop to fill my Array.

```
$global:BackupJobObjectArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

function AddBackupJobFoldertoArray ($jobservername, $backupjobfolder, $backupjobname, $jobmandant, $size, $sizeGB, $sizeTB, $BackupServer, $vbkcount, $lastmodifiedfile)
{
    $BackupJobObject = New-Object System.Object
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Jobname" -Value $backupjobname
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Mandant" -Value $jobmandant
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Servername" -Value $jobservername
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Filepath" -Value $backupjobfolder
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Size" -Value $size
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeGB" -Value $sizeGB
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeTB" -Value $sizeTB
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Backupserver" -Value $BackupServer
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VBKCount" -Value $vbkcount
    $BackupJobObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastModified" -Value $lastmodifiedfile
    $global:BackupJobObjectArray.Add($BackupJobObject) | Out-Null
}

AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server01" "folder01" "jobname01" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server02" "folder02" "jobname02" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server03" "folder03" "jobname03" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server04" "folder04" "jobname04" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server05" "folder05" "jobname05" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server06" "folder06" "jobname06" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server07" "folder07" "jobname07" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server08" "folder08" "jobname08" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server09" "folder09" "jobname09" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server10" "folder10" "jobname10" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver01" "1" "01.01.2001"

AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server21" "folder16" "jobname16" "mandant03" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver03" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server22" "folder10" "jobname16" "mandant03" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver03" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server22" "folder03" "jobname16" "mandant03" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver03" "1" "01.01.2001"


AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server11" "folder11" "jobname11" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server12" "folder12" "jobname12" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server13" "folder13" "jobname13" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server14" "folder14" "jobname14" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server15" "folder15" "jobname15" "mandant01" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server16" "folder16" "jobname16" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server17" "folder17" "jobname17" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server18" "folder18" "jobname18" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server19" "folder19" "jobname19" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server20" "folder20" "jobname20" "mandant02" "1000" "100" "10" "backupserver02" "1" "01.01.2001"


$global:BackupJobObjectArray | ForEach-Object {$_.psobject.Properties | Group-Object { $_.Jobname } | Format-Table}
```

Comment: You may try `$BackupJobObjectArray | group jobname | where count -gt 1 |% { $_.Group }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Script-scoping` instead of Global as that should be more than enough.
Then use `$script:BackupJobObjectArray` only **inside** the fuction, because outside the list is known anyway.

Instead of all those `Add-Member` lines, you can simply use `[PsCustomObject]` and add that straight away to the list.

Then finally, if I understand your question correctly, you woud like to get a table formatted list of the duplicate objects based on the JobName, and this you can do like below

```
$BackupJobObjectArray = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

function AddBackupJobFoldertoArray {
    param(
        [string]$jobservername, 
        [string]$backupjobfolder, 
        [string]$backupjobname,
        [string]$jobmandant, 
        [int64]$size, 
        [int64]$sizeGB, 
        [int64]$sizeTB, 
        [string]$BackupServer, 
        [int]$vbkcount, 
        [string]$lastmodifiedfile
    )
    $script:BackupJobObjectArray.Add([PsCustomObject]@{
        Jobname      = $backupjobname
        Mandant      = $jobmandant
        Servername   = $jobservername
        Filepath     = $backupjobfolder
        Size         = $size
        SizeGB       = $sizeGB
        SizeTB       = $sizeTB
        Backupserver = $BackupServer
        VBKCount     = $vbkcount
        LastModified = $lastmodifiedfile
    })
}

AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server01" "folder01" "jobname01" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server02" "folder02" "jobname02" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server03" "folder03" "jobname03" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server04" "folder04" "jobname04" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server05" "folder05" "jobname05" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server06" "folder06" "jobname06" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server07" "folder07" "jobname07" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server08" "folder08" "jobname08" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server09" "folder09" "jobname09" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server10" "folder10" "jobname10" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver01" 1 "01.01.2001"

AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server21" "folder16" "jobname16" "mandant03" 1000 100 10 "backupserver03" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server22" "folder10" "jobname16" "mandant03" 1000 100 10 "backupserver03" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server22" "folder03" "jobname16" "mandant03" 1000 100 10 "backupserver03" 1 "01.01.2001"


AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server11" "folder11" "jobname11" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server12" "folder12" "jobname12" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server13" "folder13" "jobname13" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server14" "folder14" "jobname14" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server15" "folder15" "jobname15" "mandant01" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server16" "folder16" "jobname16" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server17" "folder17" "jobname17" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server18" "folder18" "jobname18" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server19" "folder19" "jobname19" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"
AddBackupJobFoldertoArray "server20" "folder20" "jobname20" "mandant02" 1000 100 10 "backupserver02" 1 "01.01.2001"


($BackupJobObjectArray | Group-Object Jobname | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }).Group | Format-Table
```

Output:

```
Jobname   Mandant   Servername Filepath Size SizeGB SizeTB Backupserver   VBKCount LastModified
-------   -------   ---------- -------- ---- ------ ------ ------------   -------- ------------
jobname16 mandant03 server21   folder16 1000    100     10 backupserver03        1 01.01.2001  
jobname16 mandant03 server22   folder10 1000    100     10 backupserver03        1 01.01.2001  
jobname16 mandant03 server22   folder03 1000    100     10 backupserver03        1 01.01.2001  
jobname16 mandant02 server16   folder16 1000    100     10 backupserver02        1 01.01.2001
```

Personally I would go for a List object, but an ArrayList would also do.